# Remove all characters before "-" on each line of multiline textarea text

Tags: javascript

I am getting some text from a multiline textarea, each line is separated by a line break:

```
 1 - test1
 2 - test2
 3 - test3
 4 - test4
```

How can I remove on each line all text before the `-`, so the text will look like:

```
 test1
 test2
 test3
 test4
```

Comment: split text on base of '-' then trim the next part, or use a regular expression for that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look for no dashes and a dash and replace with an empty string for multiline data.

```js
var string = ' 1 - test1\n 2 - test2\n 3 - test3\n 4 - test4',
    result = string.replace(/^[^-]+-/gm, '');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using split and splice.

```js
const mytext = ' 1 - test1';
const arr = mytext.split('-');
const splice = arr.splice(1,1 ,'');
const final = splice.toString();
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be solved with a regular expression. Try to put down your string to check if it is possible.

here is the good website for it: https://regex101.com/